# How to migrate from Catel project to Orchestra + MahApps? (.NET 4.0)

Tags: .net-4.0, upgrade, catel, orchestra

I have a Catel project, using various Catel controls and classes, how do I migrate/update it to Orchestra (MahApps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real "conversion" required. Orchestra is a library built on top of Catel. It makes it easier for you to create applications using Fluent.Ribbon or MahApps.Metro because it takes care of all the boiler plate code for you.

If you want to "migrate", you need the following steps:

1. Decide what shell to use (MahApps or Fluent.Ribbon)
2. Decide what the MainView will be (the real content of the window)
3. Decide what the ribbon will be (if you are using the Fluent.Ribbon shell)
4. Use the bootstrapper instead of showing MainWindow as startup uri

A good way to learn how it works is to use the examples that are included in Orchestra. Each shell has their own example app.

Now you are moving to a more professional shell, a few hints:

1. Start using Command Containers (works anywhere in your app and your users can remap the shortcuts)
2. Take a look at all the other components in the [Orc.* space](http://github.com/wildgums/)